# Gap between Img and div

Tags: html, css

I have an img and div i can't find why there is a gap. I have seen [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702807/gaps-between-an-img-a-div). But it is not working for me i have also tried using margin:0. here is my [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnLHZ/). But i cant find why this gap is here. Thanks

```
<img src="http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/shapes/rectangle.jpg" class="header"/>         
<div class="body-middle">

</div>
```

css is:-

```
.header
{
width:100%;     
height:auto;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

.body-middle
{
height:50px;
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;  

background:url('http://www.clipartsfree.net/vector/large/simple_green_rectangle_Vector_Clipart.png') 0 0 repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center top;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any gap, it's just fine ?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image

Comment: Thanx for helping me i have got answer ........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `display:block` to the image.

```
.header{
    display:block;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/nnLHZ/1/)

Comment: @Hiral could you please explain how `display:block` helps here.

Comment: @Kathir by default, image is inline. inline elements leave white space between elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
.body-middle {
    margin-top: -50px; //adjust number of pixels to what works best for you
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This CSS..

```
*{
 margin:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnLHZ/2/)